# Schedule apt-get script using cron

Tags: command-line, scripts, cron, schedule

I'm kinda new in Linux and I've just learned about scheduling tasks with cron. I have this small shell script that I've been using manually till now:

```
sudo apt-get check && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Now I want to schedule it using cron so I won't manually do it every day, but it seems I can not do so. I suppose it is because it requires my sudo password in order to proceed? Is there any way I can make this work without auto-accepting the upgrades and so on?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a better idea to use "unattended-upgrades" instead.

> Its purpose is to keep the computer current with the latest security (and other) updates automatically. [[1]](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades)

To install:

```
sudo apt install unattended-upgrades
```

Read more about how to get it work: [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates).

---

To address your question, you can edit `/etc/crontab` file and run your commands using `root` user without the need of using `sudo` in your own "crontab" file.

```
nano /etc/crontab
```

and add a line like:

```
45 21 * * * root apt-get update > /home/ravexina/out.log
```

which runs `apt-get update` using `root` user at "21:45" every night and logs the output to `/home/ravexina/out.log`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it's for "learning" purpose, or at least this is how I see it.  I want to learn why it doesn't work and what can I do in order to make it work. Can you please help me?

Comment: Thanks! I tried to edit the /etc/crontab in order to make it work, but I still have some doubts it does. The script is placed in /usr/local/bin, under the name sysup. What I tried in crontab was


15 21 * * * root sysup && echo "Succes!"


Still, I had no such message displayed on my terminal. Any thoughts why? Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I was expecting that the output of the scheduled task still appear on terminal, prompting me when required input.

Comment: First of all, you are not going to see the "success" so redirect it to a file, second use absolute paths in your script to make sure it's going to be work correctly. don't forget to make your script executable too: `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/sysup` at the end you can put your commands directly in `/etc/crontab` to make sure thy really work.

Comment: Thanks, I will try so right now. Please don't mind if I send you any more message regarding this, but I hope it will work now!